# Using HighchartsPHP library in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, highcharts

I am trying to use ghunti's [HighchartsPHP](http://www.goncaloqueiros.net/highcharts.php) wrapper in CakePHP so I can use it in my project.

In the demo it says to edit the `config.php` and include the script and you then have access to the `Highchart` class to build charts. This would work for a flat php project but in MVC it works a bit differently I guess.

The first step is how to include the library in my app. I have placed the files in a directory in the `Vendor` folder called `HighchartsPHP` and in my controller file I have placed the code

```
App::import('HighchartsPHP', 'Highchart');
```

When I attempt to instatiate a new `Highchart` object I am met with

> > Error: Class 'Highchart' not found

**Question 1**: what's the correct way to include this library in my project?

---

Assuming the above is solved, I presume I would build the actual chart from its data in the controller and then pass the chart object to the view for rendering? So in one of my page actions in the controller I might put

```
$chart = new Highchart();
$chart->series[0]->name = 'Tokyo';
$chart->series[0]->data = array(7.0, 6.9, 9.5);
```

And then

```
$this->set( compact( 'chart' ) );
```

to pass to the view where I would render the chart with:

```
<?php echo $chart->render("chart"); ?>
```

**Question 2**: Is this correct and if not how should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller should be like this:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'HighchartsPHP/Highchart');

class ChartsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {        

        $chart = new Highchart();

        $chart->chart = array(
            'renderTo' => 'container', // div ID
            'type' => 'line'
        );

        $chart->series[0]->name = 'Tokyo';
        $chart->series[0]->data = array(7.0, 6.9, 9.5);

        $this->set( compact( 'chart' ) );
    }

}
```

and index.ctp:

```
<?php $chart->printScripts(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $chart->render("chart");?>
</script>
```