# where do i get wrapper classes for the Highchart js library

Tags: cakephp, highcharts

I need to include wrapper classes in vendor folder of CakePHP. I have no idea to get it done. I need some code help on sending the chart data from the controller to the view.

Anyone there to help me.

Comment: Can you please share what you done till now?

Comment: In my project i need to insert a chart. I preferred highchart would be appropriate. In order to bring the graph supposed to include the wrapper libraries to the vendor folder. I don't know how many files needed and where to get it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turned up several resources that may be  helpful for you:

- [Using HighchartsPHP library in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868242/using-highchartsphp-library-in-cakephp)
- Using Highchart in CakePHP: https://coderwall.com/p/c6yasq/using-highchart-in-cakephp
- CakePHP 2.* Highcharts Plugin: https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-highcharts
- install highchartsphp in cakephp windows: http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/install-highchartsphp-in-cakephp-windows-t30010/
- CakePHP + Highcharts: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/AUQV1TvJfx0

Comment: Thanks buddy, thaks for ur time and help. Those links were really helpful and i made it.